# OperationalError: no such column: XX - Sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 alongside python. I'm just trying to get some really basic auth going on but when my sql query gets executed I am getting the following error:

OperationalError: no such column: admin

My query looks like the following:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=%s AND password=%s;" % (username, password))
```

Any ideas? I have searched around but can't find anything

Comment: `username` and `password` are strings. Use `'%s'` in your query. Otherwise sqlite will confuse them with column name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should never use string interpolation in database queries; as well as the problem you're having, you leave yourself open to SQL injection attacks. Instead, use the parameter substitution provided by the db api.

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=? AND password=?", (username, password))
```

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel! I'll make sure to keep a note!